# apollo-link-state writeQuery does't update ROOT_QUERY in cache, preventing re-render component

Tags: reactjs, graph, oauth-2.0, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am implementing OAuth with a custom provider.
So I have `Auth` component where inside 'componentDidMount:

```
client.mutate({
  mutation: CURRENT_USER_MUTATION,
  variables: {
    token: (response.data.token.value) || null,
   },
});
```

My mutation looks like:

```
gql`
  mutation($token: String!) {
    CurrentUser(token: $token) @client
  }
`;
```

And I have resolver:

```
defaults: {
  current_user: null,
},
resolvers: {
  Mutation: {
    CurrentUser: (_: any, { token }: { token: string }, { cache }: { cache: Object }): null => {
    const { user } = decodeJWT(token);

    cache.writeQuery({
      query: CURRENT_USER,
      data: {
        current_user: {
          __typename: 'user',
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          level: user.level,
          email: user.email,
        },
      },
    });

    return cache.readQuery({ query: CURRENT_USER });
  },
},
```

And then something stamge happend, when I look inside chrome apollo debuger, I can clearly see this:

[image: chrome apollo dev tool]

So data is already inside Apollo cache, but `ROOT_QUERY` still have null as current user.

Also when I try to use `react-apollo` `Mutation` component like this:

```
<Mutation mutation={CURRENT_USER_MUTATION}>
  {(mutate: Function,): React.Node => {
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={(): Function => mutate(({ variables: { token: '123' } }: Object))}>
        Do it
       </button>
     );
   }}
 </Mutation>
```

Then it works perfectly.

**So it look like after using `cache.writeQuery` other component/cache is not notify about running mutation.**

**I will be grateful for your help :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end, I found that the problem was I different place :P My friend Michał suggest me this by making a working example of my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l57k8v3o67

So a few conclusions:
1.  component will only re-fetch/re-render when user interaction is detected. So for example click, this is why  component with clickable button works or some request to the server is made.

2. Apollo has few bugs :) I have a different component called `<PrivateRoute />`, basically checking if we have current_user and then redirect or render route, here is it: https://gist.github.com/bslipek/b11caefba31599e30d498beaf8644cec And this component has a bug with issue from ere: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/236

So basically if you render  component with a query to local-state, and you don't set `fetchPolicy='cache-first'` Apollo will fall back to default.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `CurrentUser` mutation is wrong.

This shoud work:

```
Mutation: {
  CurrentUser: (_: any, { token }: { token: string }, { cache }: { cache: Object 
}): null => {
  const { user } = decodeJWT(token);

  cache.writeQuery({
    query: CURRENT_USER,
    data: {
      current_user: {
        __typename: 'user',
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        level: user.level,
        email: user.email,
      },
    },
  });

  return {
      current_user: {
        __typename: 'user',
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        level: user.level,
        email: user.email,
      },
    }
},
```

Comment: Mutation is fine, maybe returning cache.readQuery is not good for performance (?) but works ok.